# gp.CreateFeatureClass(..) and gp.CopyFeatures(..) isn't copying all fields of feature class

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing, arcgis-9.3

How do I get the ArcGIS 9.3 geoprocessor to copy all of the fields of a feature class?

Here is a description of what I'm trying to do:

I am modifying an existing script created by a developer not on the program anymore. The script's purpose is to extract a given feature set into a zipped .gdb.  Therefore, the script takes a feature set as input. In the FeatureSet that I am attempting to export (which is a feature set representing major lakes), the fields are DEPTH, NAME, OBJECTID, Shape_Area, Shape_Length, SQKM, SQMI, and SURF_ELEV. The .gdb resulting from this script, however, only contains OBJECTID, Shape (*where'd that come from??*), Shape_Length, and Shape_Area.

I am exporting the feature set via

```
gp.CopyFeatures(featureSet, scratchGdb + os.path.sep + lyrName)
```

The .gdb is successfully created, but only *some* fields are there!  Why am I losing some of the fields in this feature class when exporting it to a .gdb?

Through using Komodo IDE, I was able to remote debug the script, and I saw that the input feature set only had the four fields that ended up in the exported .gdb.

Does this have to do with setting a schema for the feature set?

Comment: What is the purpose of creating a feature class before copying your original over to the GDB? CopyFeatures should create a new FC with all of its fields.

Comment: Are all fields visible in the layer you are using as the template to CreateFeatureClass?  Maybe only the visible ones are going across.

Comment: @Nathanus, PolyGeo, and Chad: I am modifying an existing script created by a developer not on the program anymore. I do not know why that call to `gp.CreateFeatureClass` was there. As per your recommendations, I removed the `gp.CreateFeatureClass` line and left the `gp.CopyFeatures` line there. As you said, the .gdb was created. However the same issue is occurring. In the FeatureSet that I am using, the fields in a featureSet which contains major lakes are **DEPTH**, **NAME**, **OBJECTID**, **Shape_Area**, **Shape_Length**, **SQKM**, **SQMI**, and **SURF_ELEV**. The .gdb resulting from this sc

Comment: If you're TrueLifeCoder, which you seem to be, you should place this answer as an edit to your original question. Although if you changed accounts, I guess you'd have to have a Moderator change ownership if that's even possible.

Comment: Nathanus is right, Alex.  The problem is that your account and that of TrueLifeCoder are *completely* different: they use different identifiers.  We can merge the two accounts if both of them make the request to do so.

Comment: Do you have to use a FeatureSet? What about just [selecting](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Select_%28Analysis%29) the data you need and then doing the CopyFeatures?

Comment: Yea sorry that was a mistake.  I thought I was logged in to my TrueLifeCoder account but wasn't.

Comment: I just posted the edit.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Are you running this interactively in ArcMap in the Python prompt or a standalone script? If in ArcMap, look at what PolyGeo said above. If fields are turned off in the layer properties, they might not be coming over for that reason.

Comment: Is the feature class that you create empty, or does it contain the features from the appropriate shapefile?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to create the featureclass first using `gp.CreateFeatureClass`. [`CopyFeatures`](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Copy_Features_%28Data_Management%29) should create it for you. Try that and see what you get. And it sounds like you are using a layer selection, otherwise all of your features will get copied and not just your selected ones.

Comment: I tried that and got the result mentioned in the edited question.  Please let me know why this could be.  Thanks!